# pushViewController not work with .xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

** In **  Discover.m

```
AgendaListPage *controller1 = [[AgendaListPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"AgendaListPage" bundle:nil];
    controller1.title = @"Page1";
    MissedDataListPage *controller2 = [[MissedDataListPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"MissedDataListPage" bundle:nil];
    controller2.title = @"Page2";
```

** In **  AgendaListPage.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == self.tableView){
 
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        HastagScreenTablePage *myControllerHastag = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hastagScreen"];
        myControllerHastag.detailModalForHastag = @[[getTopHastagObject[indexPath.row] gethastagName]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: myControllerHastag animated:YES];
    }
}
```

> I use https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu API Obj-C version.

I try every method but page not change when selected row. any idea ?

**EDIT :**

i change code like this

```
 HastagScreenTablePage *myControllerHastag = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hastagScreen"];
 myControllerHastag.detailModalForHastag = @[[getTopHastagObject[indexPath.row] gethastagName]];
 FirstNavControllerPage *navigationController = [[FirstNavControllerPage alloc] initWithRootViewController:myControllerHastag];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: navigationController animated:YES];
```

FirstNavControllerPage is  a UINavigationController

Now error : `Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <FirstNavControllerPage: 0x13659d5c0>.`

EDIT :

[image]

[image]

Comment: `self.navigationController` nil?

Comment: Yes you are rights self.navigationController is nil how can i fix ? I edit question

Comment: you shoud add AgendaListPage controller to Navigation controller programatically when you are creating object of AgendaListPage. e.g.    'AgendaListPage *obj = [[AgendaListPage alloc]init];
        UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj;'

Comment: `HastagScreenTablePage *myControllerHastag = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hastagScreen"];
            myControllerHastag.detailModalForHastag = @[[getTopHastagObject[indexPath.row] gethastagName]];
            FirstNavControllerPage *navigationController = [[FirstNavControllerPage alloc] initWithRootViewController:myControllerHastag];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController: navigationController animated:YES];` i change code like this still not work

Comment: no I'm talking about HastagScreenTablePage, I'm talking about the current controller i think i.e. AgendaListPage you should add this AgendaListPage controller in  Navigationcontroller

Comment: Check this image again

Answer (score 0):

For Xib you don't need to create storyboard object

just controller alloc init work

```
HastagScreenTablePage *myControllerHastag = [[HastagScreenTablePage alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myControllerHastag animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add navigation Controller in Your Storyboard. Right? if so,you will get "self.navigation == nil". Add navigation controller first and then set a root view controller. Then your pushViewController will get it's instance and work.

Comment: `HastagScreenTablePage *bbp = [[HastagScreenTablePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];` Like this ?

Comment: Right Clicked  And Drag From Navigation controller To YourFirstViewController then you will see many option to select. then select "Root View Controller"

Comment: But i use .xib how can i do that in .xib ?

Comment: I know how can i add nav. controller dude. But This page use .xib i will add image please check

Comment: I add image navigation controller connecting viewcontroller this controller call nibs.

Comment: check this image again. Your image does not show to check mark "is initial View Controller"
http://imgur.com/44KIdlN

note: look navigation controller has an arrow. do you have? This means the Navigation controller has initialized.

Comment: Yes i know , these controllers implements in Discover.m and discover have got navigation controller http://imgur.com/P4hOv1K

Comment: Also `AgendaListPage` and `MissedDataListPage` have not got viewController i call with Nib

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the identifier('hastagScreen' in your case) for the `UIViewController` in story board file, may be following code is returning nil.

```
HastagScreenTablePage *myControllerHastag = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hastagScreen"]; // myControllerHastag might be nil.
```

[image: replace YOUR_ID with hastagScreen]

Comment: HastagScreenTablePage have not got viewController addSubview in Discover.m check images

Comment: `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier ` will give you a viewcontroller object, you are assigning it to  `HastagScreenTablePage` ("HastagScreenTablePage have not got viewController" ), which i assume to be a `UIView`, its all wrong

Comment: Actually, HastagScreenTablePage have got viewcontroller but in .xib so i cannot add navigation controller ...

Comment: Then no need of navigation controller , Use code suggested by `Rahul Shirphule`